# How to get values from a context (object ) dynamically in django templates

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm a newbie in django and I'm trying to get values from an object dynamically in the template directly, but nothing seems to work:
this is what I have in the django template:

```
{% for key, value in edit.changes.items %}
<p>{{ translator.get(key) }}</p>
```

I also tried this:

```
{% for key, value in edit.changes.items %}
<p>{{ translator[key] }}</p>
```

this is the view:

```
def medical_record_edit_list(request, pk):
    translator = {
        "appointment_date" :"Fecha",
        "diagnosis_type" : " Tipo de Diagnóstico",
        "main_diagnosis" : "Diagnóstico Principal (CIE-10)",
        "related_diagnosis" : "Diagnóstico Relacionado (CIE-10)",
        "objective" : "Objetivo",
        "mental_exam" : "Exámen Mental",
        "development" : "Desarrollo",
        "employed_interventions" : "Intervenciones Utilizadas",
        "evaluation_instruments" : "Instrumentos de Evaluación",
        "agreements" : "Acuerdos",
        "therapeutic_work" : "Expectativas de la Consulta",
        "evaluation_instruments" : "Instrumentos de Evaluación",
        "remission" : "Remisiones y Contrarremisiones",
        "finality" : "Finalidad",
        "external_cause" : "Causas Externas",
        "conduct" : "Conducta",
        "exit_state" : "Estado de Salida",
        "exit_diagnosis" : "Diagnóstico de Egreso (CIE-10)",
        "exit_condition" : "Condición de Salida"
    }
    medical_record_entry = MedicalRecordEntry.objects.get(pk=pk)
    edit_list = MedicalRecordEdit.objects.filter(medical_record_entry=medical_record_entry).order_by("edit_date")
    return render(request, 'medical_record/medical_record_edit_list.html', {'edit_list':edit_list,
     'medical_record_entry':medical_record_entry, 'translator': translator})
```

I'm just trying to get something like `{{ context.appointment_date }}` as output - but for each key of the for loop that I have above

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to do something directly in template.
Of cause, you can create your own django template tag, on SO you can find many answers, how to do it in django.

But this all is really not correct, and you you can do all things simpler:

```
def medical_record_edit_list(request, pk):
    # your staff, define translator and edit_list there

    edited = (((translator[key], key, val) for key, val in edit.changes.items)
               for edit in edit_list)
    return render(request, 'medical_record/medical_record_edit_list.html', {
           'edit_list':edit_list,
           'medical_record_entry':medical_record_entry, 
           'translator': translator,
           'edited': edited 
           })
```

After that in template:

```
{% for edited_item  in edited %}
    {% for translation, key, value in edited_item %}
        <p>{{ translation }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```